# Is it possible to follow the history of files in another repository

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs

Here is the scenario :

We have an "official" repository containing some folders. This folder is owned by user A and user A should be the only one to be allowed to push on it :

```
repoA
 |
 -- folderA1
  |
  |- fileA11 .. fileA12
 |
 -- folderA2
  |
  |....
```

User B needs to maintain his own copy of folderA1 (from repoA) and should be able to merge the commits pushed by userA in its own copy. User B doesn't want folderA2

Of course, user B will commit some modifications to his own copy of folderA1 and the history of folderA1 (viewed from user B perspective) should look like that :

```
HEAD
|
*    Merge user A master into user B master
| \
* |  Last commit made by user A
* |  Previous commit made by user A
| *  Last commit made by user B
| *  Previous commit made by user B
|/
*    Initial commits made by user A
*
*
|
```

User B should not have folderA2 (from user A) in his own repository.

User B should be able to have folderB1 and folderB2 in his own repository.

Thanks

Comment: I think this http://help.github.com/subtree-merge/ should help

Answer (score 0):

Considering you can control write access at a repository level (through, for instance, [Gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/why.html)), it would be best if `folderA1` was:

- a Git repo of its own
- referenced in `repoA` as a [submodule](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html).

Controlling who update what would be more complex with [subtree merging](http://progit.org/book/ch6-7.html).

Comment: The access control is not a problem, we have gitlab and the push access is limited. We are trying the subtree merging solution now

Comment: @GhislainLeveque push access is limited per-repository. And a subtree merge would result in only one repo, which gives all users accessing that repo full write access on both parts of that repo. I don't think subtree merging is an adequate solution in your case.

Comment: Thansk for your comment. We are currently using subtree merging and it works well but we didn't have many interaction between users yet so we cannot tell if it's a good long term and "easy to maintain" solution

Comment: @GhislainLeveque those darn users! Everything just works until they start... err... using it ;)